# Spotfire Curve Draw from Data Table, Help Plotting curve from secondary data table on top of another visualization

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I am using a external data connection to build a visualization, in the DB there are two tables I am using in my Spotfire doc. I have a main table I use to build the bulk of the visualization, but in a specific vis.

I am trying to plot a "trend line" with static values that I have put into a different table in my DB. I have built the line in Lines/Curves but it does not show up in my visualization and I am not getting an error.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trend lines are really made to by dynamic and based off the underlying data, usually through some mathematical computation. Since you are using two tables, I would use a combination chart instead. In both cases, the two tables would need what ever column you are using on your X axis, in both tables, so you can relate them.

Right Click > Switch Visualization To > Combination Chart. Then on your vertical axis, put the data from your second table. You'll need to set this up in the Series by as well. Right Click > Series > Click on New Table and change Type to Line. Lastly (or first if you want), manage relations via Edit > Data Table Properties > Relations.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! So now that I have that set up, I am having an additional issue. I use the web player to display the visualization is a browser, but my categories are not showing up on the x axis?? They are just blank, in bar chart their is a property that allows me to show labels for category but not in combination?? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean they aren't showing up? Do you mean you want the selector to be shown? Can you post a picture?

Comment: The category labels for the x axis do not show up, unfortunately I can not post a picture. In properties under bar chart there is a "Category Axis" attribute that I can click "Show Labels" under the "Scale Labels" section of the window. In the combination chart properties window, I don't see a "Category Axis" attribute that I can change. I see the labels in Spotifre but not in the webplayer

Comment: You should see this under X Axis of your combination chart